# SortedSet<TestClass> comparing on equality one field and sorting by another

Tags: java, treeset, sortedset

Please review code:

```
/* Run1.java */
package test;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Run1 
{
    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        SortedSet<TestClass> s = new TreeSet<TestClass>(); 

        s.add( new TestClass("name1", 100) );
        s.add( new TestClass("name2", 10) );
        s.add( new TestClass("name3", 1) );
        s.add( new TestClass("name4", 10) );
        s.add( new TestClass("name5", 100) );

        Iterator<TestClass> it = s.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            TestClass t = it.next();
            System.out.println( t.name+' '+t.value );
        }
    }
}

/* TestClass.java */
package test;

public class TestClass implements Comparable<TestClass> 
{
    public String name;
    public int value;

    public TestClass(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int compareTo(TestClass o) 
    {
        return this.value - o.value;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) 
    {
        if (!(o instanceof TestClass))
            return false;
        TestClass n = (TestClass)o;

        return this.name.equals(n.name);
    }

    public int hashCode() 
    {
        return 31*name.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Print out

```
name3 1
name2 10
name1 100
```

as i see because `compareTo` used for checking to equality (when returned 0). But i need check for unique by field `TestClass.name` and only sort by `TestClass.value`

Comment: Your question does not make sense. `TreeSet` uses the `compareTo()` method, **not the `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods,** to determine sort order (which is a generalization of equality, in the context of a sorted set). ***Use a different data structure*** if these are not the desired semantics. That said: _caveat emptor_ - there are very good reasons for why a tree set does not use `equals()` for object equality. What if `a.compareTo(b)` is `0` but `a.equals(b)` is `false`? What if `a.compareTo(b)` is nonzero, but `a.equals(b)` is `true`?

Comment: thank you! Please advise appropriate data container. I need fast retrieve elements by key (`TestClass.value`), but key may be duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `compareTo()` and `equals()` need to be compatible in this case, which means that you need to take into account equality in the comparison. For example:

```
public int compareTo(TestClass o) 
{
    return (this.value == o.value) ? this.name.compareTo(o.name) : this.value - o.value;
}
```

which introduces a sub-order on name for objects with the same value, making the result compatible with your `equals()` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

how about hacking the compareTo method as follows:

```
public int compareTo(TestClass o) 
{
    if (this.name != null && this.name.equals(o.name)) {
        return 0;
    }


    return this.value - o.value;
}
```

This should do equality checks on name (remove duplicates) while sorting on value

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then what you want is for your compareTo to always implement the "natural order" for the class. This means the way the client of the class would expect the class the behave. Contractually, compareTo should be consistent with equals, which is why I always implement equals as:

```
return compareTo(obj)==0;
```

This guarantees consistency.

Then, if you want another sort order, you should implement another class that implements Comparable. In this way you can have class consistency and separate sort orders.

Answer (score 0):

Write comparator which compares TestClass objects.

```
public class TVComparator implements Comparator<TestClass> {
    public int compare(TestClass o1, TestClass o2) {
        if (o1.name.equals(o2.name)) return 0;
        return o1.value - o2.value;
    }
}
```

For sake of simplicity I have omitted any checks for null values.